# Display content with slide same way google play display?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I try to make a website for mobile same the way of googleplay app display content.
I using a jquery slider to do this. this is a Demo http://dev.mteen.vn:91/ip/a/a/index.html
In slide 4, i display my content and i want after scroll down this slide, other slides fixed on the top screen.
i'm using position: fixed for other slides. It work great on computer but not work on mobile.
Can any body help me?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on what devices you are testing your mobile site but overflow scroll works on Android 3 and later I'm not really sure about iOS. You could use a javascript library that can handle the scroll functionality. Checkout this link: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

For newer versions of android and iOS you can use:

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 is thing i want, thanks verymuch, But it can only scroller in all slide pages. Do you know add more scroller?